# Drop down window to edit Cocoa pop-up menu items

Tags: cocoa, interface, menu, popup, builder

I'm relatively new to Cocoa and I would like to implement the ability to add or delete items from a pop-up menu in the same way that the OS X System Preferences/Network Location pop-up works. Selecting the 'Edit Locations...' option rolls down a window that provides the ability to add to, or delete from the existing Location list. My interest in doing things this way is as much about conforming to the relevant Human Interface Guidelines as having a way to dynamically change the menu content. (I have no real problem with the 'background' coding side of things, it's the user interface that's my primary issue at this stage.)

Is this a standard IB View?

On the surface, I can't see anything appropriate, but maybe that's just my inexperience. I'm assuming that, because this is not an uncommon sort of requirement, the task should be pretty straightforward and that Apple, or someone, would even have a relevant code sample to show how to define such a window.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It looks like what I'm after is a 'sheet', a modal dialog attached to the window that contains my pop-up button. But I still haven't found a description of how to implement a sheet.

Comment: OK, got it. Hillegass (3rd Ed, Ch.25 Sheets) to the rescue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer. I found this tutorial: http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000014.php